# Is JSTL the only way to display data in views? Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring Framework MVC, so I followed the following tutorial: [Tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/). In this the JSTL library is used to display the data that the controllers return to me. The question is, are there any other alternatives to achieve this? Is JSTL the only way to display data in views? If so, which one would be better and why? Thank you.

Comment: Thymeleaf http://www.thymeleaf.org/ is one of the alternatives to build Views.

Comment: This question seems a bit opinion-based. See [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scriptlet tag but it's not the good practice
Eg.  `<%  ---your code--- %>`